# XSLT convert UTC to tz timezone

Tags: xslt

I have the following variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="time">
 <xsl:value-of select="'2020-12-26T17:33:11Z'"/>
</xsl:variable>


  <xsl:variable name="timeZone">
        <xsl:value-of select="'America/Los_Angeles'" />
    </xsl:variable>
```

The variable time is in UTC and I would like to convert it to the local timezone. I am using the following but that is not working:

```
<xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($time), xs:dayTimeDuration($timeZone))"/>
```

My expected output is: `2020-12-26T09:33:11Z`

Comment: The `format-date` and `format-dateTime` functions have place argument where you can pass in the string you have for your timezone e.g. `format-dateTime(xs:dateTime('2020-12-26T17:33:11Z'), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]', 'en', (), 'America/Los_Angeles')`, if supported, gives `2020-12-26T09:33:11`.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all the date/time/timezone functionality in XSLT/XPath is based on absolute numeric timezone offset such as -05:00, not on civil timezones such as CET or America/Los_Angeles. The one exception is format-dateTime(), which is designed to format data for human consumption. The fifth argument to format-dateTime() is "place": XPath 3.1 says:

> If the $place argument is supplied in the form of an IANA timezone
> name that is recognized by the implementation, then the date or time
> being formatted is adjusted to the timezone offset applicable in that
> timezone. For example, if the xs:dateTime value 2010-02-15T12:00:00Z
> is formatted with the $place argument set to America/New_York, then
> the output will be as if the value 2010-02-15T07:00:00-05:00 had been
> supplied. This adjustment takes daylight savings time into account
> where possible; if the date in question falls during daylight savings
> time in New York, then it is adjusted to timezone offset -PT4H rather
> than -PT5H. Adjustment using daylight savings time is only possible
> where the value includes a date, and where the date is within the
> range covered by the timezone database.

Note that this is new in XPath 3.x; the 2.0 specification only allowed a country code to be used, and was much vaguer about what it meant.